# Git Merge not working

Tags: git

I am relatively new to Git and I am hung up on merging a branch, on which I created a file together with my master branch. Here is what I have typed in my terminal:

```
chris@chris:~/GasGuruWebApp$ git branch
  08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40
* master
chris@chris:~/GasGuruWebApp$ git checkout 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40 
Switched to branch '08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40'
chris@chris:~/GasGuruWebApp$ git add app/views/allcomplications.scala.html
chris@chris:~/GasGuruWebApp$ git commit -am "added complications"
# On branch 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40
nothing to commit, working directory clean
chris@chris:~/GasGuruWebApp$ git push -u origin 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40 
host's password: 
Branch 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40 set up to track remote branch 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40 from origin.
Everything up-to-date
chris@chris-870Z5E-880Z5E-680Z5E:~/GasGuruWebApp$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
chris@chris:~/GasGuruWebApp$ git merge 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40 
Already up-to-date.
chris@chris:~/GasGuruWebApp$ ls app/views/
complicationform.scala.html  index.scala.html  interactive.scala.html  main.scala.html  newvitalsign.scala.html  patientmonitor.scala.html  vitalsignform.scala.html
```

As you can see, the file I thought I had added on branch '08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40' is not there.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40` would usually refer to a commit, not a branch. If this commit was made on a different branch, try:

`git cherry-pick 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40`

It seems like you may have named a branch that way yourself, I'd recommend using names that are more human-friendly.

It's also possible to checkout the old commit, make a branch based on that state:

```
git checkout (hash)
git checkout -b newBranchName
git add (files)
git commit -m "did stuff"
```

That's more useful when you need to start working on an older version without more recent commits involved.

Comment: It *is* possible to create a branch called `08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40`, I just tested it. Not something you want anyway…

Comment: lol... I'd assumed it was possible but you have to specifically create it yourself.

Comment: In fact it is even possible to merge it by specifying the full path: `git merge --no-ff refs/heads/08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40`

Comment: Since `git branch` showed a branch with that name, I guess that such a branch does indeed exist. But more than likely there's also a commit with that hash. I wonder what happens if you do `git merge name` where name matches both a branch and a hash?

Comment: @LindsayWinkler If you have a tag and a branch with the same name, you get some sort of "ambiguous reference" warning, so I would assume it does the same with commits.

Comment: I would think git would complain if you try to use a conflicting name... it does for existing tags/branches...

Comment: is there any way I can rename the branch named 08cdec3dc...?

Comment: You can try `git checkout 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40 / git checkout -b newBranchName / git branch -D 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40`. I've never had a branch named like this so it's odd territory

Answer (score 1):

You created a branch that also happens to be a commit ID:

> chris@chris:~/GasGuruWebApp$ git checkout 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40 
>      Switched to branch '08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40'

But when you run `git merge 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40`, it resolves that to the commit ID 08cdec3bcd62e683f250f9bb1471312f19d01e40  before hit resolves it to a branch name.

Thus, you are getting the "already up to date" message, since that commit ID already exists in your history.

The solution is to use more descriptive branch names that do not overlap with commit IDs.

Comment: is there a way I can rename this branch?